# Laravel three way polymorphic relation madness

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

Laravel 7.0

I am trying to set up a system where users can belong to
different models, like Courses or Realms. I call this a
'membership'.

A user who is a member in a Realm or Course always has a
Role within that Realm, like 'amdin', 'editor', or 'guest'

I have models for User, Role, Memberable and the Course/Realm stuff.

Like this:

```
Role ⇦1:N⇦ Memberable ⇨N:1⇨ User
               ⇩
            poly 1:1
               ⇩
      Realm/Course/YouNameIt
```

At the moment I am using a wild mix of relations to get
more or less what I want. But my approach seems rather
gross to me, or even wrong.

For example, to get a list of models that I am a member of, I write:

```php
User::find(2)->memberships()->get()
```

But this gives me a Collection of Memberables, not Realms or
Courses, which kind of sucks. Can this be remedied?

To get my first Realm/Course, I have to write:

```php
User::find(2)->memberships()->first()->memberable  // YUCK!
```

Here are my models:

```php
class User {
    public function memberships()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Memberable::class)->with('memberable');
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'memberables')
            ->withPivot(['memberable_id', 'memberable_type']);
    }

}
```

```php
class Memberable extends Model
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Role::class, 'id', 'role_id');
    }

    public function memberable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('memberable');
    }
}
```

```php
trait HasMembers
{
    public function members()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'memberable', 'memberables')
            ->withPivot('role_id')
            ->join('roles', 'roles.id', 'memberables.role_id')
            ->addSelect(['role' => Role::select('name')
            ->whereColumn('role_id', 'roles.id')]);
    }
}
```

```php
class Realm extends Model
{
    use HasMembers;
}

class Course extends Model
{
    use HasMembers;
}
```

I know that questions like "is this good" or "is this bad" are difficult to answer, so I'll ask:

- Is this so wrong that I should worry?
- How could I improve this design?
- I'll probably never have more Models that Realms and Courses that can have members. Is it smarter to ditch the whole memberable-polymorphism in favour of two separate tables? It IS nice to keep the flexibility the polymorphic approach offers.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set up more relationships

- `User` belongsToMany `Roles`
- `Roles` belongsToMany `Users`
- `User` **morphedByMany** `Realm` **using** `Memberable`
- `User` **morphedByMany** `Courses` **using** `Memberable`
- `User` **morphedByMany** `YouNameIt` **using** `Memberable`
- `Realm` **morphToMany** `User` **using** `Memberable`
- `Courses` **morphToMany** `User` **using** `Memberable`
- `YouNameIt` **morphToMany** `User` **using** `Memberable`

I'd make `Memberable` a morph pivot.

```php
class Memberable extends MorphPivot { ... }
```

With this, accessing the relationships isn't hard.

```
$user->roles      // Get an Eloquent Collection made up from $user's roles.
$role->users      // Get an Eloquent Collection made up from users that have $role.
$user->realms     // Get an Eloquent Collection made up from $user's realms.
$user->courses    // Get an Eloquent Collection made up from $user's courses.
$user->youNameIt  // Get an Eloquent Collection made up from $user's youNameIt.
$realm->users     // Get an Eloquent Collection made up from users associated with $realm.
$course->users    // Get an Eloquent Collection made up from users associated with $course.
$youNameIt->users // Get an Eloquent Collection made up from users associated with $youNameIt.
```

And maybe make User <---> Roles relationship use a separate pivot. If not, then make it a morph relationship as well (`User` morphedByMany `Role` using `Memberable`, `Role` morphToMany `User` using `Memberable`)

The thing is, if you use a central table to morph everything up, it will grow a lot. You're essentially making it do the job of 3-4 pivots (in this example). If your data grows a lot, it **might** become a problem.

Also, different relationships might need different data from the pivot table but since you're only using a single table, that would complicate things unless you opt to use a json field.